# How do I incorporate colors in flutter with 'A' before the numbers?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

Guys how can I incorporate colors like the one I attached in an image from the material design that have 'A' in their code to my flutter application.

[image: colors like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `String/Char` into your `MaterialColors`. According to the docs:

```
  /// Creates a color swatch with a variety of shades.
  ///
  /// The `primary` argument should be the 32 bit ARGB value of one of the
  /// values in the swatch, as would be passed to the [new Color] constructor
  /// for that same color, and as is exposed by [value]. (This is distinct from
  /// the specific index of the color in the swatch.)
  const MaterialColor(int primary, Map<int, Color> swatch) : super(primary, swatch);
```

So, it only takes a map of `int` values with their corresponding `Color`. For example:

```
static MaterialColor teal = MaterialColor(
    0xFF009688, // default color, normally matches [500]
    <int, Color>{
      50:  Color(0xFFE0F2F1),
      100: Color(0xFFB2DFDB),
      200: Color(0xFF80CBC4),
      300: Color(0xFF4DB6AC),
      400: Color(0xFF26A69A),
      500: Color(0xFF009688), // same as primary
      600: Color(0xFF00897B),
      700: Color(0xFF00796B),
      800: Color(0xFF00695C),
      900: Color(0xFF004D40),
    },
);

static MaterialAccentColor tealAccent = MaterialAccentColor(
  0xFF64FFDA, // default color, normally matches [200]
  <int, Color>{
    100: Color(0xFFA7FFEB),
    200: Color(0xFF64FFDA), // same as primary
    400: Color(0xFF1DE9B6),
    700: Color(0xFF00BFA5),
  },
);
```

Then you can use it like:

`teal[300]` or `teal.shade300`;

The letter "**A**" is just a short for "**Accent**" and should be used for the floating action button and interactive elements, such as:

- Text fields and cursors
- Text selection
- Progress bars
- Selection controls, buttons, and sliders Links

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, btw 0xff is for opacity which is followed by hex code of the color.

```
color: Color(0xffeeff41),
```

Comment: If I wanted to use the first 10 colors I can just write color: Colors.lime[200],   does this mean I need to use the hex code for all the colors starting from 11

Comment: If it is material colours you are talking about, the 'A' in the front means Accent, so for A100, you can use color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100], similarly for A200, A300 and so on.

Comment: here are the material design colour guidelines for your reference. https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors